# Laptop backlight sets to maximum at startup (Xubuntu 15.04)

Tags: drivers, ati, xubuntu, brightness, backlight

I've tried many solutions I've found on the Net, but had no luck with them:

- Tried first with `xbacklight = value`: output is `No outputs have backlight property`.
- Then I tried with GRUB options like `acpi_backlight=vendor` and `video.use_native_backlight=1` to the file `/etc/default/grub`, and then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot, but that doesn't work.
- I tried with the *sys* procedure, the path is `/sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0`, changing the `brightness` file works, so I put `echo value > /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness` to the file `/etc/rc.local`. The file is changed when I reboot, as I confirmed with an `echo`, but the brightness doesn't change.
- I also tried the `fglrx` method (install propietary drivers). That worked for me until I had to enter to a *tty* via CTRL+ALT+Fx (x = 1 to 6) -- I just got a black screen, and with the open-source driver (the X.org one) I didn't have this problem.

The brightness control buttons work (Fn+F2 to decrease and Fn+F3 to increase). Unfortunately, I thought the `rc.local` method semmed to work but the brightness changes when I press Fn+F3 once, and then Fn+F2  (i.e. I switch from 100% to the *minimum* value -- I tried it once again with a fresh installation and got that result).

So I want to know if there's another method to set the brightness level at startup, or at least just to "remember" the one I chose (that happens with the propietary drivers). Or if I made a mistake with the other methods.

My laptop is HP Pavilion 14-v140la, with Xubuntu 15.04 installed (x64).

Processor: AMD A8-6410 with APU

Graphics card: AMD/ATI Radeon R5 Graphics

The Linux kernel version is 3.19.0-26-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it. I edited the file `/etc/rc.local` and added this line:

```
echo 7 | tee /sys/class/backlight/radeon_bl0/brightness
```

before the `exit 0` instruction, and worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

then copy past this command to it:

```
grep acpi_video /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

this will help you find out which ACPI interface (acpi_video) controls the brightness. you'll get an output like this

```
[     7.385] (--) intel(0): Found backlight control interface acpi_videoX (type 'firmware') for output LVDS1
```

where "acpi_videoX" is "acpi_video0" or "acpi_video1".

If the command above doesn't display any output and you have a folder called "intel_backlight" under "/sys/class/backlight/", then use "intel_backlight" as the ACPI interface for the next steps.

now set the brightness to the level that you want to be set when you boot your PC.

now run this command:

```
cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness
```

Remember this value for the next step.

now create a file (as root) called fixbrightness.conf in your /etc/init/ directory.

```
gksu gedit /etc/init/fixbrightness.conf
```

past this to this file:

```
description "Sets brightness after graphics device is loaded"

start on graphics-device-added
task
exec /bin/echo BRIGHTNESS_VALUE > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_videoX/brightness
```

here, you need to:

1-replace BRIGHTNESS_VALUE with the brightness value you got under step 3.

2-replace acpi_videoX with the ACPI Interface that controls your laptop's brightness, which you found out under step 1.

**source** [Click here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html)

Comment: I have no output when I run the first command you gave me :(

Comment: go to /sys/class/backlight/ if you have a folder there called intel_backlight then use the intel_backlight instead of acpi_videoX. mentioned in the post bro. @JBEWP286

Comment: I have a folder called `radeon_bl0`. Will try the procedure with that folder.

Comment: =( Sorry, but the procedure you told me didn't work for me... In fact, I guess the problem resides in the open-source drivers, because the value can be changed manually (and I'm sure it changes with your procedure, too, although the effect only works manually and not at startup).